# Exception in Dynamic exception

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, ddl

I have been give a situation .if table exist we have to drop the table inside the procedure. if it doesnt exist we have to create the table.

so we will write

```
execute immediate 'Drop table emp';
```

if emp table doesn't exist then above statement should give exception and then we will create `emp` table, How Can we do that without checking in `user_tables` or `all_tables`

Comment: So if the table exists before you run the procedure it won't exist afterwards. But  if the table doesn't exists before you run the procedure it will exist afterwards. What a confusing workflow.

Comment: Interview questions like this should act as a red flag. Establish whether the interviewer is just testing your knowledge of PL/SQL or they really think this is a realistic task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may use such a way :

```
begin
  execute immediate 'Drop table emp';
 exception when others then
   begin
    if ( sqlcode = -942 ) then
    execute immediate 'Create table emp(id int,name varchar2(50),surname varchar2(50))';
    end if;
   end; 
end;
```

when run drops the table if exists, if don't exist drops the table.

We have some exception names spesific to the error codes, rather than using the generalized one `OTHERS`, returning from the keyword `sqlcode` such as :

`ZERO_DIVIDE(-1476)`, `TOO_MANY_ROWS(-1422)`, `VALUE_ERROR(-6502)`, `INVALID_NUMBER(-1722)` .. etc.

You may refer [Exception Handling and Related Codes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21639/exceptions.htm#TTPLS192)

Comment: Wow.. Thanks friend. Could you also tell me is there any name given to the exceptions occurred in dynamic sql?

Comment: @OnkarTiwari you're very welcome friend. I have edited the question related to the exception names.

Comment: Dear Barbaros.. Could you please answer this question as well? some frustrated people put this on hold.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52104318/oracle-query-running-slow-since-yesterday?noredirect=1#comment91163804_52104318

Comment: @OnkarTiwari Hi, dear Onkar, there are more details needed which were summarized in  Lukasz Szozda's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a homework?

If no, then this would be a rather poor design. You should not create table dynamically, better truncate the data.

If yes, then a solution with exception names would be this one:

```
DECLARE
  TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST, -942);
begin
  execute immediate 'Drop table emp';
exception 
   when TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST then
      execute immediate 'Create table emp(id int,name varchar2(50),surname varchar2(50))';
end;
```

Comment: This is just an interview question.